# Deduced template parameter order?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

What in the following is well-formed according to the standard :

```
// 1 : Deduced template parameter in the normal order
template<typename T, typename T1 = typename std::conditional<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, T, int>::type>
void f(T x);

// 2 : Deduced template parameter in the inverted order
template<typename T1 = typename std::conditional<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, T, int>::type, typename T>
void f(T x);

// 3 : Deduced template parameter before a function pointer
template<typename T>
void f(T x, void(*g)(int, int, T*));

// 4 : Deduced template parameter after a function pointer
template<typename T>
void f(void(*g)(int, int, T*), T x);

// 5 : Deduced template parameter with inversed variables
template<typename T, typename T1 = typename std::conditional<std::is_fundamental<T>::value, T, int>::type>
void f(T1 x, T y);

// 6 : Inverted deduced parameter
template<typename T, typename T1>
void f(T1 x, T y);
```

In the 3 and 4 case, if the passed types from the variable and inside the function are different, which type will be choosen : the one of the function, or the one of the variable ?

Comment: Define "ok". Well-formed _and_ well-defined _and not_ unspecified?

Comment: `if the passed types from the variable and inside the function are different` They're not. Ever. If you try to make them so then you are passing incorrect arguments and your compilation will fail.

Comment: You're missing `::value` behind the traits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(2) is ill-formed because `T` is used in the default template argument for `T1` before it is declared.  The rest are well-formed.

In (3) and (4), if `T` must be deduced from the function arguments, then `T` must be deduced to the same type in each place that it is used.  That is, if it is deduced to be one type from its use in the first function paramter and deduced to a different type from its use in the second function parameter, deduction fails and the use is ill-formed.

In (5), the default argument for `T1` will never be used--either the actual argument will be specified when a specialization is used, or the template argument will be deduced from the function argument `x`.

There is nothing special about (6):  if all of the template arguments are deduced from the function arguments, then the order in which the template arguments are declared is irrelevant.